# How add action button to google-doc?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to add button or another widget with click action to my Google Document with Apps Scripts;
How will i can do it?

```
function addButton()
{
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  // code for add button to body.
}
```

Comment: The easiest solution is to learn how to create a menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Create a menu

```
function onOpen() {
   menu();
}

function menu() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('MyMenu')
  .addItem('Function Descript', 'functionName')
  .addToUi();  
}

function functionName() {
  //a function that does nothing
}
```

Your best bet is to learn how to do this on your own so that you don't have to return here everytime you require a modification.

If you wish to add buttons I would recommend placing them on a sidebar with html.  That will take a little more effort but in the long run it will be worth learning how to build and reuse the html file.

#### Reference:

- [Custom Menus in Google Workspace](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)